# Как динамически активировать SearchView?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-menu, android-search-view

Есть кнопка поиска в меню. Необходимо либо:

- программно эмулировать нажатие кнопки поиска в меню
  или
- активировать widget SearchView

  Подойдет любой способ.

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:context=".activity.MyActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/search_hint"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        />
</menu>
```

код в активити:

```
  boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu)
  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    menuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);
    searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

    return true;
  }
```

Есть MenuItem menuItem и SearchView searchView, теперь нужно как то активировать SearchView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение которое работает и с collapseActionView в `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"`.

нужно вызвать `menuItem.expandActionView()`

Answer (score 2):

1. Заведите в активити поле `MenuItem menuItem;`
2. Инициализируйте его в `onCreateOptionsMenu` - `this.menuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);`
3. Теперь активируйте (эмулируйте клик) так: 
   `((SearchView) menuItem.getActionView()).onActionViewExpanded();`

Comment: menuItem.getActionView()).onActionViewExpanded() срабатывает частично. Клавиатура появляется, а виджет поиска не раскрывается.

Comment: @Devel0per, попробуйте убрать `collapseActionView` из `app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"`

Comment: Если убрать collapseActionView, то работает, спасибо!

Comment: @Devel0per, если ответ решает заявленную в вопросе задачу, то в можете проголосовать за него и отметить верным, нажав на стрелочку вверх и галочку слева от тела ответа)